# Android animations memory leak

Tags: android, animation

If I have infinite animation in activity and navigate away from activity, does it causes memory leak? Do I have to stop animation explicitly or is it somehow managed on framework level? What I mean by infinite animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"
    android:repeatCount="infinite">

<rotate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From developers webpage :

You should usually use the onPause() callback to:
Stop animations or other ongoing actions that could consume CPU.

Source : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html#Pause

Answer (score 0):

Not closely related, but If the leak is caused by the Animator class, e.g. holding a reference to an Activity/Fragment, you should call `animatorInstance.removeAllListeners()` in your fragment/activity `onDestroy` callback.